# Cannot configure RD Gateway to RDP through web access

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, gateway, remote-desktop-services

I have a windows server 2012 base ec2-instance. This is joined to a domain. Have installed RDS service, and configured to make it a RD Gateway server.

I can nicely access through web also. But I don't get an option to RDP to my other domain computers. Only apps that I get to access through web access is the default apps - Calculator, notepad etc.

Have configured CAP and RAP as shown below:
[image]

[image]

How can I configure in such a way that I can access all the computers in the domain through web? Can someone please help to configure RD Gateway on Amazon ec2- instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CAP only limits *who* (users/groups) can connect via the RDS Gateway (RDSG), and the RAP only limits *what* (servers) they can connect to. It has nothing to do with what's displayed in the RDS Web Access (RDSWA) page.

There's no way to automatically have all your servers show up as RDP icons in RDSWA, but if I remember correctly, one of the tabs of the interface allows you to specifiy a server to which you want to connect and it will launch an RDP client to that machine. This might be a configurable option, or I might be totally wrong. Unfortunately, I no longer have a RDSWA server around to test.

Ultimately, if your RDSG is visible on the network from which you're trying to connect (presumably the Internet), and policies in the CAP and RAP are setup to allow it, you can simply put the desired hostname in the **Computer** box of the RDP client, the hostname of the RDSG in the appropriate box and it should allow you to connect.

No need for the RDSWA interface at all in this case.

To my knoweldge, the RDSWA page is mostly used to aggregate and publish RemoteApp sources and provide a method for Windows clients to pull said links down to their PCs.

Comment: All the components are in one server (I mean web access, hosts etc). I am  on a basic level in RDS. Can you please point me how can I configure? I just need to get rdp for all the domain computers in web access.

Comment: If you re-read the answer, you'll see that there's no automatic way to have all domain computers show up in Web Access. You might be able to create RemoteApps for each system and have Web Access use those, but I couldn't begin to tell you how to do that. Not to mention it being a bad idea.

Comment: So, do you mean that I should install RD Session Host on each and every server? And then create a RDP APP?

Comment: No, you can RDP to a system without it being an RDS Session Host. I'm saying you *can* create individual RemoteApps for each server and publish them to WA, but that doing so doesn't really make sense and would be huge management burden. You already have a gateway, and in looking at your policies, you shouldn't NEED the web access entires for ever server. Presumably you know what servers exist and where you want to connect, so enter the hostname in the RDP client, specifiy the RDS Gateway in Advanced Settings and connect. That's it.

Comment: Presumably you know what servers exist and where you want to connect, so enter the hostname in the RDP client, specifiy the RDS Gateway in Advanced Settings and connect.

I have servers list of my domain. What I wants is that users must be able to connect to each server through RD web access and I think remote app is the best option. But I really dont know how can I create an remote app file for each server. Sorry, but can you help me on that??

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you here. I'm saying what you want isn't automatically doable, and the more I think about it, I'm not sure what you want is at all possible. Web Access isn't designed with this use case, so you've got a 'round peg, square hole' problem.

Comment: Why are you so tied to having them connect via Web Access anyway? Why can't you just provide them with the steps required to leverage your Gateway and be done with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22297/discussion-between-serverstackqns-and-gregl).